# why we need user_agent_alias with mechanize object?

Tags: ruby, mechanize-ruby

I just wondering for some informations about `mechanize` and found the below code from Internet:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'logger'
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows IE 9'
agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
agent.log = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Could any one please explain why `user_agent_alias` and `follow_meta_refresh` is needed when,`mechanize` itself is a browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mechanize isn't a browser. It is a page parser that gives you enough methods to make it easy/convenient to navigate through a site. But, in no way is it a browser.

`user_agent_alias` sets the signature of Mechanize when it's running and making page requests. In your example it's trying to spoof a site by masquerading as "IE 9", but that signature isn't going to fool any system that is sniffing the User-Agent header.

`follow_meta_refresh`, well, you should take the time to search for "meta" tags with the "refresh" parameter. It's trivial to find out about it, and, then you'll understand. Or just [read the documentation](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html#method-i-follow_meta_refresh-3D) for it.